# Using variable second times in function not return the same value?

Tags: scala, iterator, immutability

I start learning Scala, and i wrote that code. And I have question, why **val** which is constant? When i pass it second time to the same function return other value? How write pure function in scala?

Or any comment if that counting is right?

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException
import java.io.IOException
import scala.io.BufferedSource
import scala.io.Source.fromFile

object Main{  
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = { 
    val fileName: String = if(args.length == 1) args(0) else ""
    try {
      val file = fromFile(fileName)

      /* In file tekst.txt is 4 lines */
      println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(file)} lines")
      /* In file tekst.txt is 0 lines */
      println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(file)} lines")

      file.close
    } 
    catch{
      case e: FileNotFoundException => println(s"File $fileName not found")
      case _: Throwable => println("Other error")
    }
  }

  def countLines(file: BufferedSource): Long = {
    file.getLines.count(_ => true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`val` means that you cannot assign new value to it. If this is something immutable - a number, immutable collection, tuple or case class of other immutable things - then your value will not change over its lifetime - if this is `val` inside a function, when you assign value to it, it will stay the same until you leave that function. If this is value in class, it will stay the same between all calls to this class. If this is object it will stay the same over whole program life.

But, if you are talking about object which are mutable on their own, then the only immutable part is the reference to object. If you have a val of `mutable.MutableList`, then you can swap it with another `mutable.MutableList`, but you can modify the content of the list. Here:

```
val file = fromFile(fileName)

/* In file tekst.txt is 4 lines */
println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(file)} lines")
/* In file tekst.txt is 0 lines */
println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(file)} lines")

file.close
```

`file` is immutable reference to `BufferedSource`. You cannot replace it with another `BufferedSource` - but this class has internal state, it counts how many lines from file it already read, so the first time you operate on it you receive total number of lines in file, and then (since file is already read) 0.

If you wanted that code to be purer, you should contain mutability so that it won't be observable to the user e.g.

```
def countFileLines(fileName: String): Either[String, Long] = try {
  val file = fromFile(fileName)
  try {
    Right(file.getLines.count(_ => true))
  } finally {
    file.close()
  }
} catch {
  case e: FileNotFoundException => Left(s"File $fileName not found")
  case _: Throwable => Left("Other error")
}


println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(fileName)} lines")
println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(fileName)} lines")
```

Still, you are having side effects there, so ideally it should be something written using IO monad, but for now remember that you should aim for referential transparency - if you could replace each call to `countLines(file)` with a value from `val counted = countLines(file)` it would be RT. As you checked, it isn't. So replace it with something that wouldn't change behavior if it was called twice. A way to do it is to call whole computations twice without any global state preserved between them (e.g. internal counter in `BufferedSource`). IO monads make that easier, so go after them once you feel comfortable with syntax itself (to avoid learning too many things at once).

Answer (score 0):

`file.getLines` returns `Iterator[String]` and [iterator](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections-2.13/iterators.html) is *consumable* meaning we can iterate over it only once, for example, consider

```
val it = Iterator("a", "b", "c")

it.count(_ => true)
// val res0: Int = 3

it.count(_ => true)
// val res1: Int = 0
```

Looking at the implementation of `count`

```
def count(p: A => Boolean): Int = {
  var res = 0
  val it = iterator
  while (it.hasNext) if (p(it.next())) res += 1
  res
}
```

notice the call to `it.next()`. This call advances the state of the iterator and if it happens then we cannot go back to previous state.

As an alternative you could try `length` instead of `count`

```
val it = Iterator("a", "b", "c")

it.length
// val res0: Int = 3

it.length
// val res0: Int = 3
```

Looking at the definition of `length` which just delegates to `size`

```
def size: Int = {
  if (knownSize >= 0) knownSize
  else {
    val it = iterator
    var len = 0
    while (it.hasNext) { len += 1; it.next() }
    len
  }
}
```

notice the guard

```
if (knownSize >= 0) knownSize
```

Some collections know their size without having to compute it by iterating over them. For example,

```
Array(1,2,3).knownSize  //  3: I know my size in advance
List(1,2,3).knownSize   // -1: I do not know my size in advance so I have to traverse the whole collection to find it
```

So if the underlying concrete collection of the `Iterator` knows its size, then call to `length` will short-cuircuit and `it.next()` will never execute, which means the iterator will not be consumed. This is the case for default concrete collection used by `Iterator` factory which is `Array`

```
val it = Iterator("a", "b", "c")
it.getClass.getSimpleName
// res6: Class[_ <: Iterator[String]] = class scala.collection.ArrayOps$ArrayIterator
```

however it is not true for `BufferedSource`. To workaround the issue consider creating an new iterator each time `countLines` is called

```
def countLines(fileName: String): Long = {
  fromFile(fileName).getLines().length
}

println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(fileName)} lines")
println(s"In file $fileName is ${countLines(fileName)} lines")

// In file build.sbt is 22 lines
// In file build.sbt is 22 lines
```

Final point regarding `val`ue definitions and immutability. Consider

```
object Foo { var x = 42 } // object contains mutable state

val foo = Foo // value definition

foo.x
// val res0: Int = 42

Foo.x = -11 // mutation happening here

foo.x
// val res1: Int = -11
```

Here identifier `foo` is an immutable reference to **mutable** object.